# Common Lisp hash-table with with accented characters as keys

Tags: unicode, lisp, common-lisp, hashtable

I'm trying to create a hashtable in Common Lisp to store characters as keys, but the hashtable doesn't work if I use accented characters. It only takes one possible key with accents.

In this example I add 5 keys, and see that the hashtable shows 5 elements, then add another 5 with accents, and the table shows 6 elements, then add another “normal” 5 elements and the size goes to 11 (as expected).

What is happening? And how can I solve this?

```
(defparameter *h* (make-hash-table))
(setf (gethash #\A *h*) #\A)
(setf (gethash #\E *h*) #\A)
(setf (gethash #\I *h*) #\A)
(setf (gethash #\O *h*) #\A)
(setf (gethash #\U *h*) #\A)
(hash-table-count *h*)
(setf (gethash #\á *h*) #\A)
(setf (gethash #\é *h*) #\A)
(setf (gethash #\í *h*) #\A)
(setf (gethash #\ó *h*) #\A)
(setf (gethash #\ú *h*) #\A)
(hash-table-count *h*)
(setf (gethash #\a *h*) #\A)
(setf (gethash #\e *h*) #\A)
(setf (gethash #\i *h*) #\A)
(setf (gethash #\o *h*) #\A)
(setf (gethash #\u *h*) #\A)
(hash-table-count *h*)
```

Comment: Which implementation are you using? Have you tried to use another `test` function when defining `*h*`?

Comment: SBCL, and I don't understand what you mean with defining another “test” function.

Comment: You can provide an optional `test` keyword to `make-hash-table` which determines which function is used to test for equality of two hash keys. Check its documentation in hyperspec.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work as expected with `eq`, `eql`, `equal`, or `equalp` but then I “reduced” the question to another, because `(eq #\É #\Á)` outputs `T`.

Comment: I cannot check it myself at the moment, but my first question was regarding your CL implementation. Check its documentation if it uses UTF-8 right away of if it needs some extra configuration.

Comment: That might be in the right track. If I execute sbcl from the terminal and use `(eq #\É #\Á)` it says `NIL` (I have the `(setf sb-impl::*default-external-format* :utf-8)` line in `~/.sbclrc`) but if I do it from the SublimeREPL in Sublime Text it says `T`. Thank you. Although this answer may remain unanswerable, I might delete it.

Comment: The default test for hashtables is EQL. You also need to make sure that Lisp uses the right encoding when reading accented characters...

Comment: Just use `char=` for your test.

Comment: `eq` is for testing if the operands *are the same object*, so whether or not it returns `T` for two constant characters is a complete gamble. `eql` is guaranteed to be `T` "if [the operands] are both characters that represent the same character." http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eql.htm

Comment: If you want your code to be portable you *can't* use `char=` for the test function (see [CLHS](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mk_has.htm) for the functions you can use).

Comment: I would say that this is a bug in SBCL.   If the external format is such that `#\É` and `#\Á` are not decoded properly, then the reader should diagnose that.  Basically what seems to be going on here is that raw UTF-8 follows the blackslash, and that backlash syntax is just taking the first byte (which is `#xC3` for both characters), failing to diagnose the trailing junk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [SBCL manual](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/):

```
On non-Unicode builds, the default external format is :latin-1.
```

You want to use UTF-8. So do what the manual says, and set your environment up when you call SBCL:

```lisp
$ LANG=C.UTF-8 sbcl --noinform --no-userinit --eval "(print (map 'string #'code-char (list 97 98 246)))" --quit
"abö"
$ LANG=C sbcl --noinform --no-userinit --eval "(print (map 'string #'code-char (list 97 98 246)))" --quit
"ab?"
```

If you use SLIME or Sly from Emacs, there is a way to set it up in your init:

```lisp
(setq sly-lisp-implementations
      '((sbcl ("/opt/sbcl/bin/sbcl") :coding-system utf-8-unix)))
```

Then use a sane test function, like `char=`. You should use the most specific predicate whenever possible, in my opinion. `char-equal` is the case-insensitive version.

[Sly manual, though the above snippet works on SLIME too as `slime-lisp-implemetations`](https://joaotavora.github.io/sly/)

As noted in the comment by @Manuel if your LANG variable and friends do not use UTF-8, then you are doomed. [See this quetsion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30479607/explain-the-effects-of-export-lang-lc-ctype-lc-all#30480596)

Comment: Thanks. My problem is then with SublimeREPL. I don't know how to find a way to make it load the utf8 when opening. Is there a persistent way of writting `LANG=C.UTF-8` so that it's “read” when executing `sbcl`? Because I cannot tell SublimeREPL to “execute” `LANG=C.UTF-8 sbcl` it says _FileNotFoundError(2, "No such file or directory: 'LANG=C.UTF-8 sbcl'")_. Thanks

Comment: You can write a "start-sbcl.sh" executable script that does the right thing, and point SublimeREPL to that script.

Comment: `eql`, the default test function,  would be the same as using `char=`? `char=` isn't a valid test function to `make-hash-table` so if it isn't then `equal` or `equalp` (case insensitive) is the right choice.

Comment: @coredump I will try (although if it's not straightforward I don't know if I will be able to do it), but that might be what I need. Thanks

Comment: Alright, I solved it. In any case what I needed was what @coredump said, make my own script, but instedo of `LANG=...` I needed was `LC_CTYPE=es_ES.UTF-8` (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22823923/1834416)), the version by Spenser Truex did not work. I still don't understand but it works.

Comment: @SpenserTruex if you edit the answer mentioning `LC_CTYPE` I can mark this answer as valid ;)

Comment: It seems that you need UTF-8 all the way down.

Answer (score 2):

If, for whatever reason, you cannot change SBCL's default [external fomat](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html#External-Formats), you can always use 
`#\LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_A_WITH_ACUTE`, etc.

Comment: Yes, I know this. The thing is that SublimeREPL doesn't behave as expected and doesn't use the utf-8 external format, and I don't know how to do it.